# SQL - Select Rows based on this criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite 3, and cannot work out how to do this!

Just wondered if anyone could give any tips. I have two tables, for example:

```
Table: chefs

Name    | Gender
--------|----------
Alice   | Female
Billy   | Female
Charlie | Male
Dillon  | Male
```

and

```
Table: dishes

Dish      | Name
----------|------------
Steak Pie | Alice
Lasagne   | Billy
Burger    | Alice
Salad     | Charlie
Fries     | Dillon
```

**What I want is to display how many dishes there are, which are prepared by females (obviously, this needs to use information from both tables)**

I'm expecting a similar result to the following:

```
Name    | NumberOfDishes
--------|---------------
Alice   | 2
Billy   | 1
```

As the above is recognising that these are the only female chefs using data from the first table, and counting how many dishes these individual chefs have in the second table.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Many thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select chefs.name, count(*) 
from chefs join dishes on chefs.name = dishes.name
where gender = 'Female'
```

Comment: Thanks - this pretty much worked! Just had to add a couple of quotation marks around Female (just in case anyone reads this and has a similar issue)... But thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped :) I fixed the quotes. Btw, if it works, you should mark this question as answered.